# How to autogenerate JAXB annotations from POJOs?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, jaxb

I'd like to offer a simple webservice that takes a complex object as input parameter.
The complex object is a simple pojo, and I want to expose all the member fields via soap.

```
class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> values;
    private XMLGregorianCalendar birthDate;
}

@WebService
public clcass CustomerService {

    @WebMethod
    public String process(@WebParam(name = "customer") Customer customer) {

    }
}
```

Is there any plugin/mechanism that can auto-generate the missing `JAXB` annotations on the `Customer` class so that `JAX-WS` can publish the webservice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java First Development:
I think that you must add all annotations necessary to work by JAXB.

Contract First Development:
If you have a WSDL definition and XML definition you can use these maven plugin.

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
```

and

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
```

that generates all annotations for you.

I think which another solution is that you generate an XSD from your java class(schemagen plugin), in order to approach to "Contract First Development".

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.